# Reducer: Add item in a nested array based in an index

Tags: react-redux

I've a situation like this...

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    chat: []
}

Then I set the chat and I include this data:

```
[
 {
  "otherParty":"aaaaa",
  "thread":[
     {
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3
     },
     {
        "d":4,
        "e":5,
        "f":6
     }
  ]
 },
 {
  "otherParty":"bbbb",
  "thread":[
     {
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3
     },
     {
        "d":4,
        "e":5,
        "f":6
     }
  ]
 },
 {
  "otherParty":"cccc",
  "thread":[
     {
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3
     },
     {
        "d":4,
        "e":5,
        "f":6
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

I need to add a new item at array[1].thread something like { g: 7, h: 8, i: 9 } - In other words: I'd like to specify the index of the array and add a new thread.

How to archive this ?

```
export const addNewThread = (obj, index) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_NEW_THREAD,
    payload: {
        thread: obj,
        index: index
    }
  }
}
```

and the reducer...(I need to fill the ????)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  chat: []
}
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NEW_THREAD:
        return {
            ...state,
            chat: ?????
        }

  }
  return state
}
```

Comment: you probably want to do something like `chat = state.chat.slice(); chat[action.playload.index] = { ...chat[action.payload.index], thread: chat[action.payload.index].thread.concat([action.payload.thread]) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  chat: []
}
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NEW_THREAD:
        const chat = state.chat.slice();
        const thread = chat[action.index].thread.concat(action.thread);
        chat.splice(action.index, 1, thread);
        return {
            chat
        };

  }
  return state
}
```